# Selenium-Request with bs4 to do a click event-->Parse--> and requests.get href links

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am using selenium to open a url, where I alphabetically sort a table by clicking a header. I am then parsing using bs4 on various parameters to isolate the rows and the links of those corresponding rows in the table based off of anchor text.

```
options= Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory":r"C:\Users....." })
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver= webdriver.Chrome
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r"C:\Users\....chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
w = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

I then have to sort the table with a click event

```
Class_link= ('')
Download_link=[]
linked= []
well_id_list=['06']
number_of_wells= len(well_id_list)
fail=[]
url =('https://cogcc.state.co.us/weblink/Results.aspx?ID=' +str(well_id_list[0]))
print(url)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
for x in driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Class'):
    Class_Link = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(x).click(x).perform()#Print here I think
    response= driver.page_source
    #print(response)
    time.sleep(1)
    #retrieve_page= requests.get(response).content
    soup= bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
   # driver.quit()
```

I then Parse using Bs4

```
log_file= r'C:/Users/.....'
for well in well_id_list:
    newpath = ((r'C:/Users/..../%s') % (well)) `#Builds a new well to the 6 digit API ID in the folder`
    if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)
    table= soup.find('table')
    row= table.find_all('tr')[1:]
    for row in table.select('tr:has(>td:contains("Well Logs"))'):
        logrows= row.find_all('a', text="Download", href=True)
        #print(logrows)
        links=[]
        for path in logrows:
            link=path.find('a', href=True)
            links.append(path['href'])
            print(links)
```

I then try to retrieve the href links:

```
for i in range(len(links)):
            try:
                #r=requests.get(links[i])
                with driver.get_attribute(links[i], stream=True) as r:
                    if r.status_code==200:
                        print('Saving Log')
                    else:
                        print('Fuck')
                    with open(str(log_file)+str(well)+'/file'+str(i)+'.tif', "wb") as f:
                        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
                        time.sleep(5)
            except:
                pass
```

I get all of the href links that I need, but cannot figure out how to download the links... requests.get won't work, and I can't figure out how to have selenium take back over and get the href attributes. I am trying to figure out how to get seleniumrequests() to work in this... No luck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _requests.get won't work_ What does that mean, specifically? Where is the code for that? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: You can parse with selenium to without bs4. Can you post the whole code as it is now?

Comment: @UWTDTV How can I parse in a similar manner as I have in bs4?